# Python, pandas DataFrame, use previous year, matching workday and week number from date as forecast

Tags: python, pandas

I have a daily time series DataFrame spanning many years. I want to create a naive forecast of 'this day last year' as a forecast for the next year, however I cannot just use something like `df.shift(365)` as I want to maintain the working days versus weekends. So I want to select the day that matches the year-1, weekday and week number, then use this as a forecast going forward (or something equally good).

I was debating whether to create two columns for weekday and week number, then create a pivot_table by year, then somehow shift the years along. But I went for this approach below (which does not really work, and is really slow).

```
def forecast(row):
    # set the year lookup to the previous year, means no values for the first year
    year = row.name.year - 1
    # match the weekday as not great to compare a working day to a weekend
    weekday = row.name.weekday()
    # match the week number too, as not great comparing e.g. Feb to May
    week = row.name.isocalendar().week

    return df.loc[(df.index.year == year) &
                  (df.index.weekday == weekday) &
                  (df.index.isocalendar().week == week)]


df['prediction'] = df.apply(lambda row: forecast(row), axis=1)
```

Below is a clip of my DataFrame, I would want a new column called 'Prediction' that would be nan for the first year, but from then on equal to the previous year's date with the same week number and workday.

```
Day         Value
2012-04-01   9.56
2012-04-02   9.37
2012-04-03   9.72
2012-04-04  11.27
2012-04-05  12.56
           ...
2022-03-27  10.52
2022-03-28  10.32
2022-03-29  11.19
2022-03-30  12.66
2022-03-31  15.34
```

How can I do this? In something like Excel, you could create columns for each parameter, then simply select the year, week number and working day you are after and drag down the formula. I am guessing there is a similar way using Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe as follows.

- Use [`datetime.date.isocalendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) to get year, week, and day.
- Feed the result to [`datetime.date.fromisocalendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar), but minus 1 year.
- Finally, use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to retrieve the previous-year values.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

date_rng = pd.date_range('2012-01-01','2014-12-31', freq='D')
data = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=10, size=(len(date_rng),))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                  index=pd.Index(date_rng, name='Day'), 
                  columns=['Value'])
```

**Code**

```
df['Prediction'] = df.index.isocalendar().apply(
    lambda x: datetime.fromisocalendar(x.year-1, x.week, x.day), 
    axis=1).map(df.Value)

print(df[df.Prediction.notna()].head())

               Value  Prediction
Day                             
2012-12-30  8.103599    9.405936
2012-12-31  1.846680    1.559113
2013-01-01  9.155027    6.992394
2013-01-02  8.264289    3.495970
2013-01-03  1.571457    6.596947
```

It may seem odd that the `notna` data starts at `2012-12-30` rather than `2013-01-01`, but this makes sense if you look at the `isocalendar` results:

```
df.index.isocalendar().loc['2012-12-30':'2012-12-31']

            year  week  day
Day                        
2012-12-30  2012    52    7
2012-12-31  2013     1    1

df.index.isocalendar().loc['2012-01-01':'2012-01-02']

            year  week  day
Day                        
2012-01-01  2011    52    7
2012-01-02  2012     1    1

# So that:
np.array_equal(df.loc['2012-01-01':'2012-01-02', 'Value'].to_numpy(), 
               df.loc['2012-12-30':'2012-12-31', 'Prediction'].to_numpy())
# True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much perfect, only thing is I get `ValueError: Invalid week: 53` which I get around with an if statement in the lambda function `lambda x: dt.datetime.fromisocalendar(x.year - 1, x.week, x.day) if x.week != 53 else np.nan, axis=1)`